# Can I load additional libraries in Gitpod without creating my own Docker image?

Tags: c++, github, libraries, gitpod

I have recently tried out [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/), which seems to be a quite cool tool.

For testing purposes, I have opened some C++ GitHub repository of mine that uses Boost (among other libraries). Unfortunately, Boost does not seem to be installed in the Docker image, so my code does not compile.

I know about the possibility of [creating own Docker images](https://www.gitpod.io/docs/42_Config_Docker/), but I was wondering if there are alternative, easier options as well. Does Gitpod provide any Environment Modules-like option to dynamically load/unload certain "commonly used" libraries or do I always have to provide my own Docker instance in this case?

Comment: A good way is to use gitpod config file, .gitpod.yml. You can refer to the section "Update Flutter dependencies in a Gitpod config file" in this post https://medium.com/@jacksonzhou666_71188/gitpod-flutter-productivity-on-the-go-for-mobile-app-developers-cc2495049d52

Comment: Or, you can use Ubuntu for base image on Dockerfile like [I've done for running old Ruby 2.3.8 and Heroku CLI](https://github.com/kevinhq/gitpod-dockerfile-collections/blob/master/.ruby-2.3.6-with-heroku.Dockerfile).

Answer (score 4):

I work on Gitpod. Thank you for trying it and the compliment :)

We didn't want to invent yet another module system for Gitpod.

Instead, we decided to support Dockerfiles and build them on-demand, because Dockerfiles allow using all those amazing module systems that are already out there: Debian's [packages](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages), Alpine's [packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages), [Node Version Manager (NVM)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), [Ruby Version Manager (RVM)](https://rvm.io), [SDKman](https://sdkman.io), etc. Basically any Linux-compatible package manager down to simple `wget`.

You can also use own Docker images, but I find Dockerfiles more convenient because you can check them into git and thereby version them together with your source code. It's dev-environment-as-code and should be shared across the team. Also, you don't need to bother with building and pushing them to a registry (e.g. hub.docker.com).

What Gitpod does offer, hoever, is a [selection of Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/u/gitpod) ([src](https://github.com/gitpod-io/workspace-images/)). The most prominent one is [gitpod/workspace-full](https://github.com/gitpod-io/workspace-images/blob/master/full/Dockerfile), which it Gitpod's default image.

To get back to your question about the easiest way to get the right modules into your Gitpod development environment:

1. inheriting from [gitpod/workspace-full](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitpod/workspace-full/) is very convenient.
2. If you don't want (2), copy'n'pasting sections from [gitpod/workspace-full](https://github.com/gitpod-io/workspace-images/blob/master/full/Dockerfile) is convenient.
3. Often, putting `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev` into your Dockerfile is enough. This is APT to install the package `libboost-all-dev`.
4. Most software projects have documentation on how to build them under Linux. These instructions usually work in Dockerfiles, too.
5. Search on [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com) for useful Docker images. You can inherit from those images or find their Dockerfiles and copy'n'paste sections from there.

Comment: How does one make the changes in Dockerfile to become active? I tried adding `apt-get install ngrep` to .gitpod.Dockerfile and committed the change but nothing happened.